# How do I trim the grass that's growing between the links of a chain link fence?

Tags: lawn

I have a long stretch of chain link fence, and there is some grass that grows into the links.  When I try to trim it using a basic lawn trimmer, all that ends up happening is I chew up trimming wire and the grass stays put.  Is there anything I can do to trim this down easily?

[image]

Comment: Trim it with systemic weedkiller. Then plant something that will climb up the fence, if you want to make it look nicer.

Comment: It's a *lot* of fence, something like 100 feet or more.  Is there anything that can be planted easily that would do that climbing without needing to  plant dozens of vines?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to examine why the fence is there, and if the purpose permits it to raise the fence up on its support so that there is a clear space between the bottom links and the ground. Then when you pass with the trimmer the only obstructions will be the posts which are easier to avoid than the less visible chain links.

A slight modification would be to arrange the bottom of the fence so that it can be detached from its posts and temporarily held out at an angle, perform the trimming and then replace the fence. Perhaps you can find some snap clips at the hardware store that would enable this.